# How to run multiple sites in Kestrel on Azure Asp.NET MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, kestrel-http-server

I want to start multiple sites at one Azure host. But I can't find any information about ASP.NET MVC 5. Is it possible? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "one Azure host?"

Comment: I dont know how to name it right. I mean i pay for one hosting space and i need to place there 3 simple sites

Comment: I suggest posting a screen shot of the Azure portal to indicate the item that you are buying, because it is not clear what you are trying to do. For instance, are you talking about a single Azure Virtual Machine? Are you talking about a single Web App? Are you talking about a single Hosting Plan?